# Manually disable a module

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, I could manually edit the `{system}` table in the database to disable a stubbon module.  In my Drupal 8 site, this table is gone.

How can I manually disable a module in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 62):

The Drupal 7 `system` table data is now stored in the `config` table in Drupal 8 against the `core.extension` parameter.

**Solution 1: Update configuration**

You can run the following code using `drush eval` or may be using the Devel module's provision to `Execute PHP Code`.

```
// Read the configuration.
$module_data = \Drupal::config('core.extension')->get('module');

// Unset the modules you do not need.
unset($module_data['MODULE_NAME']);

// Write the configuration.
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('core.extension')->set('module', $module_data)->save();
```

You can do this all in a quick one-liner with `drush`.

```
drush eval "\$module_data = \Drupal::config('core.extension')->get('module'); unset(\$module_data['MODULE_NAME']); \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('core.extension')->set('module', \$module_data)->save();"
```

**Solution 2: Edit config table if you cannot execute PHP**

If the site is broken because of the problematic module and you can't even run PHP code, then may be you can edit the `config` table directly.

In the row in the `config` table where `name = "core.extension"` and edit the BLOB column `data`. The `data` is a serialized PHP array where you have to remove the module you want to get rid of from the `module` key of the configuration.

**Solution 3: Fast and dirty solution**

- Remove the module from the file system
- Truncate the table `cache_config`

However, this solution might result in messages saying the module does not exist in file system which mean something is wrong. But at least the broken module gets disabled and you can access your site in most of the cases.

**Clearing Cache**

Sometimes you might have to clear cache after following the above steps. Read this handy [documentation on how to clear cache](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/administering-drupal-7-site/clearing-or-rebuilding-drupals-cache).

Comment: In terms of uninstalling modules I think this is the best solution.

Comment: If you need to uninstall a module but can't because the tables for the module are missing, you can use the third option with `drush eval`. An example one-liner is: `drush eval "\$module_data = \Drupal::config('core.extension')->get('module'); unset(\$module_data['example_module']); \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('core.extension')->set('module', \$module_data)->save();` Note the escaped dollar sign so that the command line doesn't misinterpret `$module` as a Bash variable.

Comment: Cheers for the lazy one liner! Missing a quote at the end though

Comment: It's pretty much essential you do a cache clear, and then export config so the config doesn't try to re-install until you're ready.

Comment: I was getting a WSOD when going to the site's Status Report due to missing module (yet another D8 UX fail). I tried all 3 solutions above. Although they did fix the WSOD on the Status page; when going to update.php, i still see the error. After cr, cron and updb; the warning still shows. So solutions listed above are not complete.

Comment: After doing all the solutions listed there was still a system.schema entry in the key_value table for  the missing module. Deleting that cleared out the warning.

Answer (score 21):

- Manually edit the `config` table where `name = 'core.extension'` and 
  remove the module from the data blob which is a serialized array.
- Be aware to decrement the module array length as well `(...s:6:"module";a:HERE;{...)`
- Truncate the `cache_config` table from phpmyadmin or using command-line.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. The answer should read "Manually *edit* the {config} table". The text portion to remove from the BLOB content is: `i:0;s:8:"name of the module";`

Comment: This answer helped solve a situation where a module could neither be uninstalled nor re-installed because a custom entity it defined was missing.

Comment: @hendrick this may have worked for you but the string to remove each module should be structured as `s:8:"name of the module";i:0;`. What @valli meant was that the array describing the number of modules should be decremented in number by the amount of modules removed. The begining of the blob in my setup is `a:4:{s:6:"module";a:59:{`, which is an array of 59 modules. If you delete two change that array value to 57.

Comment: If you don't want to delete the module from the serialized value manually, use this php snippet to remove it: 
`$a = 'DATA_COLUMN_FOR_CORE_EXTENSION_ROW';

$b = unserialize($a);
unset($b['module']['MACHINE_MODULE_NAME']);
$c = serialize($b);
print $c;`

Answer (score 16):

Do this:

```
rm -rf modules/your_stubborn_module
rm -rf sites/default/files/php
```

Comment: Depending on the module, you might have to delete some entries from the config table (see valli's answer) and some other tables.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: You have to run `drush cache-rebuild` too

Comment: Thanks for this: this worked on our Drupal version "8.9.13". We, of course, had to purge the cache tables (cache_) as well.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to update anything related to Drupal configuration, in this case `core.extension`, use Drush:

[Drush 8.x in this example]

```
drush cedit core.extension
```

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 8, try to removing the module from your module folder and run rebuild.php.

Try `drush pm-uninstall module-name` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Drush. Drupal 8 is still defining what "disabling modules" should be. There is an [ongoing discussion](http://drupal.org/node/1199946) if there should be that option or it should be removed.

Comment: I'm developing locally on a windows PC and last time I looked Drush wasn't ready for Drupal 8. I'll have to look again.

Comment: @bumpaw Drush should work on Windows as well. That will at least help you locally. When it comes to production servers, I know many shared hostings don't provide you with Drush or even SSH which usually makes the management way more cumbersome. http://www.drush.org/drush_windows_installer

Comment: And,  using drush,  how does one "manually remove" a module in a way that is different than the UI process?  You don't appear to have answered the question.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of the other answers but kept getting a drupal error message. To solve it I had to remove a row from the key_value table (look for the module name in the name column)

Answer (score 3):

This is how, I manually removed a module named "better_messages" from my Drupal 8 instance. As soon as I installed the "better_messages" module, the site went down. So there was no way to uninstall the module from user interface. I dont have Drush installed. I have done many settings given in forums, but this is how it finally worked for me.

1 Renamed the module to old_better_messages in modules folder.

2. Through the url, ran http://IP:port/foldername/rebuild.php. This ensured that site is back, but only in read-only mode. I couldnt do the admin activities or edit articles.
3. Used following command to delete the entry from database

DELETE FROM key_value WHERE collection='system.schema' AND name='better_messages';

In my case, there was no entry in the database. I think it might have got deleted because of the various stunts that I did earlier.

4. Then using DB visualizer, I deleted entries from all the tables that starts with cache.

This resolved the issue.
This is based on my interpretation of https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215

Comment: your solution worked like a charm! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for that. ***This module was posted in Aug-2013 on drupal.org***. In case somebody needs.

[Disable modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_modules)

As stated on the page of this module,

> Drupal 8 has removed the ability to disable modules for many reasons.
>   [See #1199946: Disabled modules are broken beyond repair so the
>   "disable" functionality needs to be
>   removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/1199946) and many other issues in
>   the queue of various core and contributed modules.
>
> This module brings back the ability to (temporarily) disable modules
>   from the UI or with Drush. Note, that there's no guarantee for your
>   content, config or even your site after you disable a module.

Answer (score 1):

Jigarius' answer above, *sort of worked...*

I had to: // Read the configuration.

```
$module_data = \Drupal::config('core.extension')->get()['module'];
```

Which *should* do the same thing. Not sure why it didn't work as Jigarius wrote it...