# How to remove the Themekey module after its Installation failed?

Tags: 8, installation

I installed the module [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey), but the installation failed with a WSOD. Now every page gives me the same 'The website encountered an unexpected error'.

So I need to remove themekey, but how can I do so? The watchdog table doesn't include any message relating to this problem, so is no help. Can I disable/remove it via the database, or am I stuck with rebuilding the whole system?

Comment: Check your server logs (not the database). they'll have the real error in it. Kind of need to know what that error is to advise

Comment: Refer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72927/manually-disable-a-module

Comment: [Mon Jul 18 07:31:26.983226 2016] [:error] [pid 5390] [client 127.0.0.1:48669] Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\Exception\\InvalidLinkTemplateException: "Link template 'edit-form' for entity type 'themekey_rule' must start with a leading slash, the current link template is 'themekey_rule.edit'" at /data/www/shgc8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php line 89

Comment: Preceding entry:[Mon Jul 18 07:32:14.392837 2016] [:error] [pid 5409] [client 127.0.0.1:48671] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\\themekey\\Theme\\ThemeKeyNegotiator' not found in /data/www/shgc8/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 268

Answer (score 2):

Use [Drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/) `drush pm-uninstall themekey` or [Drupal Console](https://drupalconsole.com/) `drupal module:uninstall themekey` to disable themekey from the command line.

Comment: Drupal console outputs the same error: [ERROR] Link template 'edit-form' for entity type 'themekey_rule' must start with a leading slash, the current link    
 template is 'themekey_rule.edit'

Comment: @davem Hmmm try `drupal module:uninstall themekey --force`

Comment: @davem WOW looks like you got yourself in quite the pickle, that DEV version of D8 Themekey is from 2014, a ton of stuff in D8 changed since then, there was 0% chance of it working.

Comment: @davem Backup your DB first, then search for themekey in your db and remove all those tables.

Comment: I tried that - I couldn't find any reference to themekey. I've bitten the bullet and started afresh. 90% of what I've done so far is new modules, anyway - they're intact. Thanks all for the suggestions,.