# error: Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\syslog\Logger\SysLog' not found in /lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 272

Tags: 8, debugging

I just activated the module syslog in an almost fresh D8 install and now it has crashed. =( How do I deactivate a core module like this manually or fix the issue?

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Run www.yoursite.com/update.php, this clears the cache as well (helpful if you can't get in the admin UI anymore and drush is not available). If this doesn't help, your installation is somehow corrupted. Could be a download error or an update that was not following the correct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a local install, you could install [Drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603018), and then: `drush dis module`. Or you can go [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72927/manually-disable-a-module) for more sophisticated solutions.

Comment: I do not have drush.
I also tried to go into the core.extension and that got a white screen with a general things are broken message.

I tried to set error messages to verbose through settings.php and I receive this:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

InvalidArgumentException: No check has been registered for access_check.permission in Drupal\Core\Access\CheckProvider->loadCheck() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Access/CheckProvider.php).
Drupal\Core\Access\AccessManager->performCheck('access_check.permission', Object) (Line: 135)