# Unable to uninstall a module

Tags: 8, database, console

When I try to uninstall the "Commerce license" module, the following error appears :

> drupal module:uninstall commerce_license

```
[ERROR] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table                                                      
         'www.domaine.com.mg433jdr_commerce_license__license_role' doesn't exist: UPDATE                                
         {commerce_license__license_role} SET deleted=:db_update_placeholder_0                                          
         WHERE bundle = :db_condition_placeholder_0; Array                                                              
         (                                                                                                              
             [:db_update_placeholder_0] => 1                                                                            
             [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => role                                                                      
         )
```

I do not know what to do. How to uninstall this module ?

Thank you

Comment: Check this one: https://www.drupal.org/node/2081695

Comment: @sarika Thank you, but what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this, is a quite similar response for this question: [Manually disable a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72927/manually-disable-a-module) take a look. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this cleanly ?
How to recreate the missing tables ?
I have installed composer and console.

Answer (score 0):

Where condition occurs, once you know no other module would be effected,  after a DB backup, you may fix this simply temporarily skipping  validation with

```
  public function validate($module) {

    return ;
```

inside `web/core/modules/field/src/FieldUninstallValidator.php`

Once your module is uninstalled, remove that `return;` absolutely crucial for an healthy site.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall module using drush with the command:
drush pmu commerce_license -y

Comment: Thank you i do this with console and it does not work

Comment: What error do you get there?

Comment: Everything is in the question

Comment: Ok. So, I ll consider that you are getting the same error on drush console.