# Class Drupal\dfm\EventSubscriber\DfmSubscriber not found when try to remove the Drupella File Manager

Tags: 8, caching, plugins

I installed the *Drupella File Manager* module for Drupal 8.8, but I have Drupal 8.7. I received this error.

> Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem::scanDirectory()

I don't need the module anymore, so I'm trying to remove it. Because of the same error on the uninstall page, I'm trying to manual remove it.

First, I removed *dfm* (which is the module machine name) from the `$module_data` configuration as described in [Manually disable a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72927/manually-disable-a-module/221736).

Then, I deleted the *dfm* directory from the /modules directory, but now I receive this error.

> Class 'Drupal\dfm\EventSubscriber\DfmSubscriber' not found in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() (line 265 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).

How can I resolve this problem?

Are there other module files that cause problems?

Clearing the cache doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I commented the line that causes the first error and then uninstalled the module via the uninstall page